# Laravel: using lists() to include children

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a query that outputs something like this:

> {"id":1,"name":"Text1","parent_id":"0","created_at":"2016-04-27
>   02:28:45","updated_at":"-0001-11-30
>   00:00:00","children":[{"id":19,"name":"Text2","parent_id":"1","created_at":"2016-04-29
>   18:04:14","updated_at":"-0001-11-30
>   00:00:00","children":[{"id":2,"name":"Text3","parent_id":"19","created_at":"2016-04-27
>   02:28:45","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","children":[]}]}]}

Notice that each item returned has a `children` property that returns all children related to that item.

I need to be able to get a list of all the `id`, including the ones under `children`.

In this case, I need it to output simply:

```
[1, 19, 2]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Not with `lists`. You may have to `foreach` through it.

Comment: Let's say this query is something like `Model::all()->with('children')`, you could then do a `->lists('id')` off of that query and it should give you all ID's include `children`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it only returns the top level items, not the children. :/

Comment: What is the query you're using please?

Comment: `Post::all()->with('children')`

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
$parent = Parent::all();

// L5
$children = $parent->children->lists('id');

// L5.1
$children = $parent->children->lists('id')->all();

// L5.2
$children = $parent->children->pluck('id');
```